# catching dismiss event ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using angular 6 and ngx-bootstrap 3.0.1

I display a modal and I want to be able to show a discard/cancel confirmation when the user try to close the modal after updating the form.

I have no issue when the user use my custom close button, but I don't know how to call my closing function when he use the backdrop-click outside the modal.

How can I handle the backdrop-click cleanly to be able to display my confirmation message?

Comment: could you add your code plz ?

Comment: The examples are really clear https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-events

Comment: Disable backdrop-clicking, force your user to click button for closing modal... Hide modal after clicking, after that do whatever you want...

Answer (score 1):

Open your modal with options

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ExampleModal, {
  ignoreBackdropClick: true,
  keyboard: false
});
```

In ExampleModal place this code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     document.documentElement.addEventListener('click',  this.hideIfIsBackdropClick.bind(this)); 
}

hideIfIsBackdropClick(event: any): void {
     if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        this.hide();
     }
}

hide(): void {
   if (anyBooleanHere) {
      this.bsModalRef.hide();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ngx-bootstrap documentation page, you can easily find your solution: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-events

To see what events are triggering,

On your component side,

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-events',
  templateUrl: './events.html',
  styles: [`
    .card {
      margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
      padding: 8px;
    }
  `]
})
export class DemoModalEventsComponent {
  @ViewChild(ModalDirective) modal: ModalDirective;
  messages: string[];

  showModal() {
    this.messages = [];
    this.modal.show();
  }
  handler(type: string, $event: ModalDirective) {
    this.messages.push(
      `event ${type} is fired${$event.dismissReason
        ? ', dismissed by ' + $event.dismissReason
        : ''}`
    );
  }
}
```

On your template side,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal()">Open a modal</button>
<br><br>
<pre class="card card-block card-header" *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</pre>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #modal="bs-modal"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-events-name"
     (onShow)="handler('onShow', $event)"
     (onShown)="handler('onShown', $event)"
     (onHide)="handler('onHide', $event)"
     (onHidden)="handler('onHidden', $event)">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-events-name" class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Just another modal <br>
        Click <b>&times;</b>, press <code>Esc</code> or click on backdrop to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

As I understand, you can check $event like this:

```
if($event.dismissReason == 'backdrop-click')
this.myFunc();
```

Comment: onHide event is triggerred when the hide action begin, What I want is to execute my own closing code when the user click outside of the window since I want to be able to cancel the hide.

Comment: @ArthurSaint-Genis I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: You can do it after disabling backdrop-click for not closing window, see here (Backdrop options): https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-disable-backdrop

Comment: how about calling the modal from component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `ngOnDestroy()` to detect when the user close the modal